# Match common words in two files, and add info from one file to the other

Tags: python

is there a way to find matches between the first word in two files ([0]=[0], and then add the second word [1] from one file to the other in common lines?

Example:

File 1:

```
Cow 3
Lion 5
Monkey 2
```

File 2:

```
Lion meat
Goat grass
Gorilla banana
```

Desired output:

```
Lion 5 meat #common first word between files + second word from file 2 in file 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Convert data in both the files to a dictionary and you are done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections
with open('file1') as f1, open('file2') as f2:
    my_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for x in f1:
        x = x.strip().split()
        my_dict[x[0]].append(x[1])
    for x in f2:
        x = x.strip().split()
        if x[0] in my_dict:
            my_dict[x[0]].append(x[1])
```

my_dict will be like:
    {'Lion': [5,'meat'], ....}

Comment: For this to work, you need to know that `'Lion'` is the common key. Does not seem to be what was asked.

Comment: @Pyson yep, this will take `Lion` as common key, and it will work perfectly, give it a try.

Comment: But it will also create every other key. The only way to tell the common keys is the length of the list.

Comment: @Pyson updated the solution, i haven't seen about the common word, my bad. thanks for notifying

Comment: Your update is only 1/2 way there. Now you still have `my_dict` with some keys from `f1` that are not in `f2`. You would have `{'Lion': ['5','meat'], Cow:['3'], Monkey:['2']}` Again, you will only know if there are common keys between `f1` and `f2` by the length of the dict. It is really better to have two dicts as the other solution here have.

Comment: Length of the list in each dict entry is the only way you can see common keys. (ie `['5','meat']` vs `['3']` for example)

Answer (score 1):

Given those two files, you can read the files into dicts:

```
with open(fn1) as f1, open(fn2) as f2:
    d1=dict([line.split() for line in f1])
    d2=dict([line.split() for line in f2])

>>> d1
{'Lion': '5', 'Monkey': '2', 'Cow': '3'} 
>>> d2
{'Gorilla': 'banana', 'Lion': 'meat', 'Goat': 'grass'}
```

Then you can use a set to figure out the common elements:

```
for key in set(d1.keys()).intersection(d2.keys()):
    print key, d1[key], d2[key]
```

Prints:

```
Lion 5 meat
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate dictionaries form the given text files and then compare their keys to get the common key and simply print the values of that key from both the dictionaries.

```
def get_dict(filename):
   dictionary = {}
   with open(filename, "r") as data_:
      data = data_.readlines()
      for line in data:
         key, value = line.split()
         dictionary[key] = value
   return dictionary

dict1 = get_dict("testing.txt")
dict2 = get_dict("testing2.txt")
```

Now since you got 2 dictionaries then you can find the intersection between both of them as :

```
for key in set(dict1.keys()) & set(dict2.keys()):
   print key, dict1[key], dict2[key]

>>> Lion 5 meat
```

Comment: It is better to loop over the file line by line rather than read the whole thing in one gulp with `data_.readlines()` Just do `for line in data_:` instead. Cuts memory use by 50% and with no loss in speed.

Comment: @Pyson Thanks would take care of this :)